# on x86 how are doubles passed to a function

Tags: c++, windows, debugging

I have the following function that takes 3 double arguments. Inside my debugger when a break on this function is reached. Inspecting the arguments to the function I don't see the 3 double arguments.

On an x86 platform are double arguments to a function stored on the stack?

Below is the function and disassembly in windbg. Why don't I see the values passed in to the function as Args to Child in windbg?

```
    vector<double> calculate_quadratic(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        double discriminant = (b * b) - 4 * a * c;
        vector<double>result;

        try
        {
            if (discriminant < 0)
                throw Bad_Value{};
            else
            {
                double d = sqrt(discriminant);
                double px = (-b + d) / (2 * a);
                double nx = (-b - d) / (2 * a);

                result.push_back(px);
                result.push_back(nx);
            }
        }
        catch (Bad_Value)
        {
            cerr << "invalid value" << endl;
        }

        return result;
    } 


     0:000> kb
     # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child
    00 003dfd2c 0126ad86 003dfe30 00000000 3ff00000 quadratic!calculate_quadratic
    01 003dfe84 0126ba6e 00000001 0043d080 0043dd18 quadratic!main+0xc6
    02 003dfe98 0126b8d0 ac1dec02 00000000 00000000 quadratic!invoke_main+0x1e
    03 003dfef0 0126b76d 003dff00 0126ba88 003dff0c quadratic!__scrt_common_main_seh+0x150
    04 003dfef8 0126ba88 003dff0c 772c336a 7efde000 quadratic!__scrt_common_main+0xd
    05 003dff00 772c336a 7efde000 003dff4c 777f9f72 quadratic!mainCRTStartup+0x8
    06 003dff0c 777f9f72 7efde000 77465726 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
    07 003dff4c 777f9f45 01261127 7efde000 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
    08 003dff64 00000000 01261127 7efde000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

    0:000> r
    eax=003dfe30 ebx=003dfd48 ecx=acd07c23 edx=582e27d8 esi=003dfd50 edi=003dfd4c
    eip=01268f70 esp=003dfd30 ebp=003dfe84 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac po nc
    cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000212
    quadratic!calculate_quadratic:
    01268f70 push    ebp

    0:000> dv /t /v
    003dfd38          double a = 1
    003dfd40          double b = -3
    003dfd48          double c = 2
    003dfd0c          double discriminant = 1.7499487580265442e+127
    003dfcf4          struct Vector<double> result = struct Vector<double>
```

Dumping the ChildEBP of the top frame I can now see the arguments on the stack in reverse order - In this case i used 10 three times which is represented as **4024000000000000**

```
0:000> kb
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child
00 004cfac4 0017ad86 004cfbc8 00000000 40240000 quadratic!calculate_quadratic

0:000> dd 004cfac4
004cfac4  5a23da80 0017ad86 004cfbc8 00000000
004cfad4  40240000 00000000 40240000 00000000
004cfae4  40240000 ed0a64cf 00000000 00000000

0:000> .formats 4024000000000000
Evaluate expression:
  Hex:     40240000`00000000
  Decimal: 4621819117588971520
  Octal:   0400440000000000000000
  Binary:  01000000 00100100 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
  Chars:   @$......
  Time:    Fri Dec 18 11:22:38.897 16246 (UTC - 5:00)
  Float:   low 0 high 2.5625
  Double:  10
```

Comment: I am not sure about windows, but on linux, there applies the System V Application Binary Interface, where the registers XMM0 to XMM7 are used to pass floating point arguments. Yous hould also dump these registers.

Comment: I'm looking at the top frame of the stack: 00 003dfd2c 0126ad86 003dfe30 00000000 3ff00000 quadratic!calculate_quadratic ---- I will try your suggestions....

Comment: @overseas Are you sure that's true for an x86 build (32-bit)?

Comment: this is independed from x86 or x64 - SSE registers is used for double

Comment: Keep in mind that if this is a function internal to your program, the compiler might have chosen to use a different calling convention.

Comment: @J... I have no idea about windows, but on linux there is no difference between 32bit and 64bit.regarding this aspect. You should read the introduction to the mentionned interface description, there you will see that 32-bit compilers are explicitly included.

Comment: arguments in stack. but task in interpretation here. windbg simply show args as integer. but not as double

Comment: On an unrelated note: The exception handling needs to be revised. It is used for control flow only here. A better idea is usually to let the exception propagate outside the function, to report, that it cannot fulfill its promise. Someone up the call stack can decide, whether it can handle the exception. This function cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default calling convention for C/C++ is [`cdecl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl).  In this calling convention, when building for x86, arguments are passed on the stack in reverse order.  Compiler options or function decorations can override this behaviour, of course.

Looking at your WinDBG output, the first three stack entries (args to child) are :

```
003dfe30 00000000 3ff00000
```

Since a `double` is 64 bits wide you're only looking at one and a half of your arguments.  The first entry looks to be the contents of EAX...perhaps a compiler optimization has pushed EAX to the stack at the point your breakpoint hit?  The next value is `00000000 3ff00000`, which is LE of `3ff0000000000000 = 1(IEEE754)`, the leftmost argument and the last to be passed to the stack in cdecl.

Comment: But look at the top frame of my stack I don't see any values that looks like the arguments passed in.

Comment: @RbMm: Except you pass 9 or more floating points. Which is quite unreasonable of course.

Comment: @RbMm: This is conflict with the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx). And I'm pretty sure that at least with [/fp:precise](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx), floating point values are passed on the stack (for x86). x64 always uses the SSE unit.

Comment: @IInspectable - yes, I mistake here. xmmN is pushed to stack in x86 function call

Comment: According to wikipedia, floating-point is passed via the x87 FPU registers. Even if these registers are arranged in a stack-like manner, it has nothing to do with the memory stack.

Comment: @galinette - no, I looking code - really xmm registers pushed to stack as usual integers in function call

Comment: @IInspectable : by "stack" you likely mean the x87 stack, which is in fact a set of registers, not the memory stack.

Comment: @galinette: By *"stack"* I meant the area of memory pointed to by the ESP register.

Comment: @galinette function *return values*, if they are floating point types, are returned in ST0 (x87 unit).  Arguments to the function, however, are passed on the stack.  It is the function's responsibility to move the values into the x87 unit.

Answer (score 0):

How arguments are passed is compiler dependent and can often be changed by options or compiler directives.

Most x86 compilers will use either the x87 FPU stack (ST0-ST7 registers) or the SSE registers (XMM0-XMM7) if  for passing floating point arguments. On MSVC, this is controlled by the /arch and /fp options.

Comment: `/arch` and `/fp` have no impact on the calling convention.  If you consider that calling code *has to know where to put the arguments* then there is nothing the compiler can do to modify this behaviour.  The function itself may *use* those registers, of course, but it can't expect to find its arguments there because there is no means of the calling code knowing that it should put the arguments there.  That's what calling conventions are for, and the rules of the calling convention are not flexible.